# Mono FormBorderStyle = None

Tags: c#, mono

I have some application on C# which was written for .NET 2.0.

Main form has property `FormBorderStyle = None`.

Now I try to use Mono 2.10.8 instead of .NET 2.0, and let's see this (left - Mono, right - .NET):

[image]

In Mono I still have smaaaaall border around form. As I can understand - it's a bug of Mono. But maybe someone know workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

set the border color White like the form.